# In a RCL circuit; where V_C > V_L is the phasor angle leading or lagging?

Tags: phase-shift, reactance

Is this example correct in stating that the phasor angle is leading by 38.323deg?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the voltage across the capacitor is different to that across the inductor, the circuit can be assumed to be series wired. And, because the voltage is greater it means that the capacitive reactance is greater than the inductive reactance and hence, \$X_C\$ is greater than \$X_L\$. This means that \$X_C\$ dominates and the phase angle is such that current leads the applied voltage.

> *Is this example correct in stating that the phasor angle is leading by
>   38.323deg?*

I cannot tell whether the example calculation is correct because capacitance, inductance and frequency are not stated.